# One Commandhandler for multiple MenuItems

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my xaml-code i have a menu with items like the following:

```
<Menu x:Name="menu" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <MenuItem Header="Root">
            <MenuItem Header="Sub1" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ???}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Sub2" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ???}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Sub3" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ???}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Sub4" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ???}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Sub5" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ???}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Sub6" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ???}"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Command is a Property of type ICommand. The implementation is

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

In the constructor of my viewmodel i have a line:

```
this.Command = new RelayCommand(OnMenuItemExecute);
```

The method for OnMenuItemExecute is:

```
private void OnMenuItemExecute(object parameter)
{
   // Here i want to know which menuitem executed the command
}
```

I just don't know what i sould pass as commandparameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the reference to the menu item you can use a relative source of self.

```
<MenuItem Header="Sub1" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></MenuItem>
```